# How do I fix Ionic Cordova Plugins Error?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm, cordova-plugins

I am building an app and when I test it, I get an error for most cordova plugins the I use:

Object(**WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_ionic_native_core**["cordova"]) is not a function. (In 'Object(**WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_ionic_native_core**["cordova"])(this, "navigate", { "successIndex": 2, "errorIndex": 3 }, arguments)', 'Object(**WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_ionic_native_core**["cordova"])' is an instance of Object)

this kind of error comes up when I try to use the DocumentViewer plugin.
I have already looked all over the internet for answers but no luck...

In the terminal:

```
ionic cordova plugin add uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator
npm install @ionic-native/launch-navigator
```

I imported:

```
import { LaunchNavigator } from "@ionic-native/launch-navigator/ngx";
```

and then called my function:

```
nav() {
 this.launchnavigator.navigate("<my location>");
}
```

Comment: hope you are calling plugin's method after device ready event.

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari of course, it happens a few pages after the first initialization...